# What exactly does $wp_filesystem->abspath() return?

Tags: plugins, wp-filesystem

The real problem I have when using the `$wp_filesystem` is defining the correct paths. In the documentation of the filesystem the path (for example for the plugins directory) is usually set like this: `$plugin_path = str_replace(ABSPATH, $wp_filesystem->abspath(), MY_PLUGIN_DIR);`

I tried to understand this but I failed because I couldn't find out what `$wp_filesystem->abspath()` is actually supposed to return. When I `var_dump()` it I get `false`. Could somebody explain to me why we can not simply use the `ABSPATH` variable in functions like `$wp_filesystem->put_contents()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out the source of `abspath()`:

```
public function abspath() {
    $folder = $this->find_folder(ABSPATH);
    // Perhaps the FTP folder is rooted at the WordPress install, Check for wp-includes folder in root, Could have some false positives, but rare.
    if ( ! $folder && $this->is_dir( '/' . WPINC ) )
        $folder = '/';
    return $folder;
}
```

.. you'll see it's main purpose is to get the "calculated" path for the filesystem method. For example, with FTP, the FTP account's root path might be deeper/further down the *actual* document root. Other methods might also not work with just `ABSPATH`, hence the `find_folder()` call (which is actually a wrapper for [`search_for_folder()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_filesystem_base/search_for_folder/) which does the real work).

Hence why you've seen something like:

```
$plugin_path = str_replace(ABSPATH, $wp_filesystem->abspath(), MY_PLUGIN_DIR);
```

...since `MY_PLUGIN_DIR` will have been constructed (at some point) based on `ABSPATH`, but within the context of the filesystem API that path may be invalid - so we replace `ABSPATH` with the calculated `abspath()` before writing.